# How do I integrate a matrix function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, function

Let's say I have a function which takes a real number ***x*** and returns a matrix ***M(x)***. How do I evaluate the following?

[image]

As an example, the function I'm trying to integrate is given by:-

[image]

Here, **k** is a constant and **A** is a matrix.

I tried using the `int` function, but it seems to work only for scalar functions. I'm new to Matlab. Could someone help me out?

Comment: please, provide an example of M(x)

Comment: you do it numericaly, e.g http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html

Comment: if you have a matrix then you integrate each matrix element itself, using previous link

Comment: @brainkz: I've edited the question for an example.

Comment: @NikosM. Thank you! I'll get back to you if I encounter difficulties.

Comment: @AntonSchigur, sure, if this solves your issue i can add an answer as well

Comment: @AntonSchigur you might find this [post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/38572-integration-using-a-vector-as-function-parameter) on how to vectorize integration helpful (ii.e integrate matrix without loops per element as one command)

Comment: a similar [question on scicomp](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8198/integration-of-matrix-valued-function-using-matlab) which points to same direction

Comment: @NikosM.: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me! The link to scicomp had exactly what I was looking for! Please post it as an answer so that I may accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab (latest, 2015) provides the [integral](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) function to numericaly compute integrals of functions

For functions that have a multi-dimensional domain (e.g matrix-valued functions) you can use the  `'ArrayValued',true` option

> **Vector-Valued Function**
>
> Create the vector-valued function
>
> `f(x) = [sin x, sin 2x, sin 3x, sin 4x, sin 5x]`
>
> and integrate from `x=0 to x=1`. Specify `'ArrayValued',true` to
>   evaluate the integral of an array-valued or vector-valued function.
>
> ```
> fun = @(x)sin((1:5)*x);
> q = integral(fun,0,1,'ArrayValued',true)
> ```
>
> q =
>
> ```
> 0.4597    0.7081    0.6633    0.4134    0.1433
> ```

Alternatively, you can integrate the matrix-valued function element-wise, i.e per-element using loops, plus, one can also try to [vectorize the operation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) to one without-loops (for example see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/38572-integration-using-a-vector-as-function-parameter))

related [question on scicomp.se](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8198/integration-of-matrix-valued-function-using-matlab)