# Continuous time system discretization, and matrix exponential, Output truncated

Tags: matlab, controls, discretization

There is a continuous-time system shown below:
[image]
[image]

The matlab codes are:

```
t=0.01;
syms s;
a2=[0 0 -285.7143;0 -0.4533 9.0662;5.2650 -5.2131 -42.5958];
b2=[571.4286;0;82.5714];
c2=[1 0 0];
A2=expm(a2*t);
B2=(int(expm(a2*s),0,t)*b1);
```

However, when I calculate B1, the computer displays 'output truncated'.

please help me.

thanks a lot.

Comment: FYI, `b1` is not defined in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's necessary to use symbolic math for this integral of a matrix-valued function. Instead, you can use [`integral`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) with the [`'ArrayValued'` option](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html#input_argument_namevalue_arrayvalued):

```
t = 0.01;
a2 = [0 0 -285.7143;
      0 -0.4533 9.0662;
      5.2650 -5.2131 -42.5958];
integral(@(s)expm(a2*s),0,t,'ArrayValued',true)
```

This is much faster and returns a result very similar to `syms s;` `double(int(expm(a2*s),s,0,t))` (ignore the minuscule imaginary parts due to numerical error). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34478912/2278029).